# Drawing complex contours on Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

### Question

I want to include three contours in a paper I'm currently writing. Unfortunately I almost have no experience with Tikz and the deadline is soon. I would really appreciate a clean code for these contours. If possible, please include the following in the code:

- the C contours should be equal in size
- the axes in the R contour not that long
- distance from rede line to H+ and H- is the same as the radius of the Omega-semicircles
- Gamma+ is defined as a "quarter"-ellipse from gamma+iT to the start of H+ and with center  the line gamma+it but at height of H+ (analogous for Gamma-)

Please make the parameters in the code clear so that if needed I would be able to adjust them easily. Most importantly the distance from the red line to H+ and H- (which is also the radius for the small circles). Thank you.

[image]

### My Solution

Thanks to the answer of MS-SPO I was able to write the Tikz Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[->] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$\text{Re}$};
\draw[->] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$\text{Im}$};
%\node at (2.2,0) {R};
%\node at (0,2.2) {I};


\newcommand\g{2}
\newcommand\T{10}
\newcommand\e{0.5}
\newcommand\Rp{1}
\newcommand\Ip{2}
\newcommand\ly{(\T-\Ip-\e)}
\coordinate (A) at (\g,\T);
\coordinate (B) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (C) at (\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (D) at (\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (E) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (F) at (\g,-\T);
\draw (A) -- (F) ;
\draw (B) -- (C);
\draw (D) -- (E);
\draw (\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:-90:\e);
\draw (\g,\T) arc(90:180:\T cm+\Rp cm and \T cm - \Ip cm -\e cm);
\draw (\g,-\T) arc(-90:-180:\T cm +\Rp cm and \T cm + \Ip cm -\e cm);
\end{tikzpicture}



\newpage


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[->] (-12,0) -- (12,0) node[right] {$\text{Re}$};
\draw[->] (0,-12) -- (0,12) node[above] {$\text{Im}$};
%\node at (2.2,0) {R};
%\node at (0,2.2) {I};


\newcommand\g{2}
\newcommand\T{10}
\newcommand\e{0.5}
\newcommand\Rp{1}
\newcommand\Ip{2}
\newcommand\ly{(\T-\Ip-\e)}
\coordinate (A) at (\g,\T);
\coordinate (B) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (C) at (\Rp,\Ip+\e);
\coordinate (D) at (\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (E) at (-\T+\Rp,\Ip-\e);
\coordinate (F) at (\g,-\T);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\draw (D) -- (E);
\draw (\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:270:\e);
\draw (-\T+\Rp,\Ip+\e) arc (90:270:\e);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! It might be more constructive to express your question as a general one, so that others can benefit from your answer. Try to identify the generic task that you are failing at, show what partial answers you already found on the web, and ask about it, rather than "can you do my figure for me because the deadline is near"?

Comment: You say the parameters should be easy to adjust, but from the diagram, it's not clear whether gamma, Gamma, and iT are vertical vs horizontal measures.

Comment: @jessexknight I assumed a little bit of familiarity with complex analysis. Small gamma denotes the horizontal measure and T the vertical measure of the line. Big Gamma is just a name for the (quarter)-ellipse.

Comment: @J..yB..y If the code includes general parameters others can easily benefit from the answers to this question. Besides the names for the paths, which should be fairly easy to change, these contours permanently appear in complex analysis.

Comment: @vitamind Assuming familiarity with your subject area reduces the number of people who might be able to help you; do-this-complicated-thing-for-me reduces the number who may be willing to do so. If you are in a hurry, you really have a couple of choices. You might get lucky and somebody is bored and interested enough in your question. (If your picture included a duck, this would be more likely.) You could hire somebody to do the work for you professionally. You could use a GUI programme such as Inkscape, which has a less steep learning curve (and can produce Ti*k*Z code or PDF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a generic question like this, especially without any code showing your attempts, here's an answer on a similar level of generality.

I assume you mastered creating a `tikzpicture` environment, which compiles. All comments happen inside this environment.

Let's focus on the path.

Specify those 6 coordinates, like:

```
 \coordinate (A) at (7,8);
```

[image: path]

Next, start drawing a closed path, like this; start with linear segments to see, it turns out right:

```
   \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- cycle;
```

It may be a good idea to look those terms and concepts up in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/), including its 4 tutorials.

Replace the segment from (C) to (D) by an `arc`.

If the other two curved pathes don't need to match a circle, look for `[out= .., in=...]` statements to introduce some bending.

For refinement for the arrows you may want to have a look at the `decoration` library.

Placing all those texts, use `\node at (..,..) {$\gamma$};`.

That's it, more or less.

**P.S.**: To gain more flexibility to create and place the 3 drawings, you may consider putting them into a `\pic`. Simplified, this works much like a macro.

Comment: How can I introduce variables like this: Let x=2 and y=3. Then \coordinate (A) at (x,y) and  \coordinate (B) at (x-1,y/2)?

Comment: Several options: a) see ch. 14., b) use TeX \def. But honestly, that‘s a bit overdone for a handful of coordinates.

Comment: I managed to get pretty far, thank you. I only have one problem left: I have defined variables \x=2 and \y=3. However the expression \x+\y cm outputs only \y cm. How can I change this?

Comment: @vitamind, good question. I'd post it as a question, either extending this one (which may be puzzling for future readers), or as a new one: there you could/should post your code, a screenshot and a link to this prior question. By doing so (posting code which compiles) you'll get very precise answers.

Answer (score 2):

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % load your figure, and adjust opacity
    \node[opacity=0.1](fig){\includegraphics[width=.94\textwidth]{handscript.jpeg}};
    % draw coordiate system
    \draw[thin, gray, step=0.2](fig.north west) grid (fig.south east);
    \draw[thick](fig.north west) grid (fig.south east);
    \draw[->, thick](fig.west) -- (fig.east)node[below]{$x$};
    \draw[->, thick](fig.south) -- (fig.north)node[above]{$y$};
    \foreach \x in {-7,...,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
        {
            \node[below left] at (\x, 0) {\x};
            \node[below left] at (0, \x) {\x};
        }
    % pick points manually and connect them
    \begin{scope}[line width=2pt, decoration={markings, mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}}]
        \draw[postaction={decorate}](-1.4, 7.4) to[out=175, in=45] (-6.5, 6);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}](-6.5, 6) -- (-3.2, 6);
        \draw(-3.2, 6) to[out=335, in=25, looseness=1.8](-3.2, 5.4);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}](-3.2, 5.4) -- (-6.5, 5.4);
        \draw[postaction={decorate}](-6.5, 5.4) to[out=290, in=170] (-1.4, 1.4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[line width=2pt, decoration={markings, mark=between positions 0.25 and 0.75 step 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}},postaction={decorate}](-1.4, 1.4) -- (-1.4, 7.4);
    % TODO

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]